# How to whether a user is watching a tab or not?

Tags: chat

I am developing a simple chat application in which I have the following requirement.Whenever an user is not watching the tab(the tab in which chat script is running) I want to change it's title as "x sent message" and whenever the user is not watching the tab I show nothing but the document's title.How to achieve this?I am using javascript for client side programming...

Comment: What platform are you targeting?

Comment: Okay what programming language, and what framework are you using for your UI?

Comment: i am using javascript for clientside and php for server side

Comment: See answer I posted below

Answer (score 0):

To detect if your tab is active in browser use the following code below.

```
window.onfocus = function () { 
  // means tab is active
}; 

window.onblur = function () { 
  // means tab is inactive
};
```

If you have jQuery you can use the code below.

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    // means tab is active
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    // means tab is inactive
});
```